# Quickblox User field and location

Tags: quickblox, quickblox-android

I am doing an android app project on quickblox. I want to add more fields in the users panel. how can I do that. Also how to integrate location in my app so that I can get the location of the person who logs in

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options now:

1. You can have location filed with CustomObjects module

https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-customObjects-android#Add_Custom_Data_structure_to_your_application

and then to create a special class like **UserParams** and have a single record per user with all additional data.

2. Use user's **customData** field https://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-android#Custom_data

but you can not filter users by **customData** field